# Linking my Obj-C framework with a Swift Framework

Tags: ios, swift, frameworks

I am building a framework that contains links to other frameworks, and the parent Framework is Obj-C. One of the child frameworks is Swift and I am getting errors 'module not found'.

How do I link a Swift framework to an Obj-C framework ? If this task was to simply add Swift source code to Obj-C source code, then I would know what to do...but it's not. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What module is not found?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need a bridging header. If I have this right, you have a framework written in Objective-C, but your Xcode project written in Swift. In that case, you have to create a bridging header and then use #import in the bridging header to access the code in Swift. You would then import the framework in the swift page/class that you want to implement code into. [Here is a great video on YouTube on how to do it!](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lon5YVMUxHQ)

NOTE: In the video, there is a #ifndef, #define, and #endif ... which I don't believe you need in Xcode 7.

Comment: Hi. Sorry dude that isn't quite right. I have one framework nested within another. So framework A is objective C and framework B is Swift. Framework B is nested within Framework A. what i mean by nested is 'linked as a dependency' (which is not actually linking because i get an error).

Comment: Are the two libraries separate (or can you make them separate)? Are you trying to incorporate Swift code into Obj C?

Comment: I'm sorry Dan I don't know what you mean when you say 'separate' ?

Comment: Can you tell me the two frameworks you are using and their links?

Comment: Both frameworks are custom. Why do you need that information anyway ?

Comment: Ok, I was reading your question wrong...sorry about that! Is there any way you can convert the objective - c framework into swift? The other idea I have is creating a bridging header and importing the obj c framework into your swift project and then imposing the obj c framework into the swift framework.